# Why do I get validation Errors (xhtml 1.0)

Tags: html

```
          <div id="leftNav">
                <ul id="mainmenu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="articles.html">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="media.html">Media</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                         </ul>              
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                         <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="email.html">Email</a></li>
                            <li><a href="location.html">Phone</a></li>
                            <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                 </ul>


            </div>
```

This code is perfect for my vertical drop down menu. however code validation hates it?

my results are here for validation, take a look please.

> document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul",
>   "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag  end tag for "li" omitted, but OMITTAG
>   NO was specified
>
> Error/Warning Type    Count Total errors: 4 Total warnings:   1 Total
>   nesting errors:   0 Total messages:   0

Comment: You're missing closing `<li>` tags

Comment: I'd love to know what the -1 was for? Seems like a well formed question to me, 3 answers in 4 minutes.

Comment: XHTML requires that all elements be closed, some of the <li> are not

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answers! Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close each principal `<li>` elements. When you close your inner `<ul>` list you have to close the `<li>` element which correspond, to pass to the next item of the main list. This portion will be (x)HTML valid:

```
      <div id="leftNav">
            <ul id="mainmenu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="articles.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.html">Media</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                     </ul></li>              
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                     <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="email.html">Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="location.html">Phone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
             </ul>


        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Maxime for your help, i'm new so I don't keep the closing in mind. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

your missing some closing `</li>`'s. Below is a corrected version:

```
 <div id="leftNav">
            <ul id="mainmenu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="articles.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.html">Media</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                     </ul>  
                </li>            
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                     <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="email.html">Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="location.html">Phone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
             </ul>


        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Liam! I'm new to web design so I forgot to close, although my navigation worked perfect, but no more errors on validation now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="leftNav">
            <ul id="mainmenu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="articles.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.html">Media</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                     </ul></li> <!-- here -->        
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                     <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="email.html">Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="location.html">Phone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                    </ul></li> <!-- here -->
                 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
```

You just have to close the `li`-tags after a nested `ul`-element.